# Titanium: Embedding a website in a WebView producing "Maximum call stack size exceeded"

Tags: javascript, titanium

Building a Titanium application using sdk 5.1.0. Opening a `WebView` is producing a `Maximum call stack size exceeded` JavaScript error **on the embeded website itself**

However, opening the same website within the browser works fine. The error only occurs using Android (Both simulator and device).

Is there a way to increase the callstack size for the WebView component in android devices?

Answer (score 0):

When the call stack exceeds, it is not because the call stack is too small, it usually always is because you have an infinite loop. So say you monitor the `load` event of the WebView, and you change url based on that, it will load again, url will change again, etc.

In this case, you say it is triggered because of only a webview added. That means your javascript on your site is doing something to loop it. Are you for example changing the layout of the site based on width through JavaScript?

Again, call stack exceeds is almost always due to infinite loop. Check your code properly!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As mentioned, the same URL works fine on a regular desktop browser (and mobile browser infact). No events on window resize either. I understand the cause of an infinite loop and have checked my code. Although not ruling it out, im confident there isn't an infinite loop. I thought the call stack size may be significantly lower wiithin a WebView compared to a desktop JS engine